# Perl tainting via regular expression

Tags: regex, perl, security, taint

## Short version

In the code below, `$1` is tainted and I don't understand why.

## Long version

I'm running [Foswiki](http://foswiki.org/) on a system with perl v5.14.2 with `-T` taint check mode enabled.
Debugging a problem with that setup, I managed to construct the following SSCCE. (Note that I edited this post, the first version was longer and more complicated, and comments still refer to that.)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T
use strict;
use warnings;
use locale;
use Scalar::Util qw(tainted);
my $var = "foo.bar_baz";
$var =~ m/^(.*)[._](.*?)$/;
print(tainted($1) ? "tainted\n" : "untainted\n");
```

Although the input string `$var` is untainted and the regular expression is fixed, the resulting capture group `$1` is tainted. Which I find really strange.

The [perlsec manual](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) has this to say about taint and regular expressions:

> Values may be untainted by using them as keys in a hash; otherwise the
>   only way to bypass the tainting mechanism is by referencing
>   subpatterns from a regular expression match.  Perl presumes that if
>   you reference a substring using `$1`, `$2`, etc., that you knew what you
>   were doing when you wrote the pattern.

I would imagine that even if the input were tainted, the output would still be untainted. To observe the reverse, tainted output from untainted input, feels like a strange bug in perl. But if one reads more of perlsec, it also points users at [the SECURITY section of perllocale](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#SECURITY). There we read:

> when use locale is in effect, Perl uses the tainting mechanism (see
>   perlsec) to mark string results that become locale-dependent, and
>   which may be untrustworthy in consequence. Here is a summary of the
>   tainting behavior of operators and functions that may be affected by
>   the locale:
>
> - Comparison operators (`lt`, `le` , `ge`, `gt` and `cmp`) […]
> - Case-mapping interpolation (with `\l`, `\L`, `\u` or `\U`) […]
> - Matching operator (`m//`):
>
>   Scalar true/false result never tainted.
>
>   Subpatterns, either delivered as a list-context result or as `$1`
>     etc. are tainted if use locale (but not `use locale
>     ':not_characters'`) is in effect, and the subpattern regular
>     expression contains `\w` (to match an alphanumeric character), `\W`
>     (non-alphanumeric character), `\s` (whitespace character), or `\S`
>     (non whitespace character). The matched-pattern variable, `$&`, `` $` ``
>      (pre-match), `$'` (post-match), and `$+` (last match) are also
>     tainted if use locale is in effect and the regular expression contains
>     `\w`, `\W`, `\s`, or `\S`.
> - Substitution operator (`s///`) […]
>
> [⋮]

This looks like it should be an exhaustive list. And I don't see how it could apply: My regex is not using any of `\w`, `\W`, `\s` or `\S`, so it should not depend on locale.

Can someone explain why this code taints the varibale `$1`?

Comment: I presume it's not tainted if you remove (the weird way of writing) `use locale;`? Wouldn't hurt to send this to `p5p` using the `perlbug` tool. There appears to be a bug in Perl if not a bug in the docs.

Comment: what is wrong with `Scalar::Util qw(tainted)`?

Comment: @mpapec: Nothing wrong with `Scalar::Util::tainted`, it yields the same result. I just pasted the code Foswiki uses here, since it might reduce the dependencies of that code a little bit. I don't know if everyone has `Scalar::Util` available, the docs suggest using CPAN for it.

Comment: Scalar::Util has been a core module since 5.8.0, more than a decade ago.

Comment: @ikegami: Reported at https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=120675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There currently is a discrepancy between the documentation as quoted in the question, and the actual implementation as of perl 5.18.1. The problem are character classes. The documentation mentions `\w`,`\s`,`\W`,`\S` in what sounds like an exhaustive list, while the implementation taints on pretty much every use of `[…]`.

The right solution would probably be somewhere in between: character classes like `[[:word:]]` should taint, since it depends on locale. My fixed list should not. Character ranges like `[a-z]` depend on collation, so in my personal opinion they should taint as well. `\d` depends on what a locale considers a digit, so it, too, should taint even if it is neither one of the escape sequences mentioned so far nor a bracketed class.

So in my opinion, both the documentation and the implementation need fixing. Perl devs are working on this. For progress information, please look at [the perl bug report](https://rt.perl.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=120675) I filed.

For a fixed list of characters, one viable workaround appears to be a formulation as a disjunction, i.e. `(?:\.|_)` instead of `[._]`. It is more verbose, but should work even with the current (in my opinion buggy) perl versions.